# c++ I get this error bad_array_new_length

Tags: c++

So I created a program to simulate dice throws and then prints the result(Homework :) ).
Now I got a bad_array_new length and think I know where it occurs, but I don't really understand why. It probably is a logic error, if someone could find it or give me a Pointer it would be amazing.

```
int* CalculateThrows(int dice_one, int dice_two, int throw_count)
{
    // I think the error occurs here 
    int *digits = new int[(dice_one * dice_two) + 1]{ 0 };
    digits[0] = dice_one * dice_two+1;

    if (throw_count > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < throw_count; i++)
            digits[GetRandomValue(dice_one) + GetRandomValue(dice_two)]++;
    }
    return digits;
}
```

This is how I call the Method and go through the array later:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int * values = CalculateThrows((int)argv[1], (int)argv[2], (int)argv[3]);
    for (int i = 1; i < values[0]; i++)
    {
        cout << i << ". Has been thrown: " << values[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: You should rather use a `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: Instead of the array?

Comment: Instead of the pointer.

Comment: `(int)argv[1]` nope, this is wrong. Don't guess at syntax. Get a C++ book.

Comment: `(int)argv[1]` doesn't do what you think it does. To convert from a `char*` to integer use `atoi()`.

Comment: and you're leaking memory (use e.g. vector instead of a c array as previously suggested)

Comment: First verify that your input is what you expect it to be by adding `cout << (int)argv[1] << "," << (int)argv[2] << "," << (int)argv[3] << endl;` as the first line in `main`. Then you figure out why it's not what you expect it to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`argv[1]` is a pointer to the string containing the first command line argument. So if you call your program `./program 6 5 4`, `argv[1]` will be the string `"6"`, not the number `6`. You should use `atoi(argv[1])` to get the number.

You should also check if `argc` is at least `4`, before you are using `argv[3]`.

```
std::vector<int> CalculateThrows(int dice_one, int dice_two, int throw_count)
{
    std::vector<int> digits (dice_one * dice_two, 0);

    if (throw_count > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < throw_count; i++)
            digits[GetRandomValue(dice_one) + GetRandomValue(dice_two)]++;
    }
    return digits;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc < 4) return -1;
    std::vector<int> values = CalculateThrows(atoi(argv[1]), atoi(argv[2]), atoi(argv[3]));
    for (size_t i = 0; i < values.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << i << ". Has been thrown: " << values[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually just don't show it for better readability, but got quite a few checks before my program call, but thanks, I will try your suggestions :)